# Camera PreviewSize Automatically Change when takePicture

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm using **getOptimalPreviewSize()** method on SurfaceChanged method. After using it when I click take picture button PreviewSize return first size and come back.

It have to stay same preview size. Why is it change?

[image]

Here Codes:

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){
   @Override
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
       if (pictureFile == null){               
           return;
       }           

       try {

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
           fos.write(data);
           fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Method.PictureCallBack", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Method.PictureCallBack", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        camera.startPreview();
  }
};

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){
       @Override
       public void onShutter() {}
};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){
       @Override
       public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {}
};

public void takePicture() {
    mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);

}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Preview size and picture sizes are different. Use getPreviewSize() to get the dimensions of the preview on screen. And using getPictureSize() you can get the exact dimensions of the picture that will be taken when you call takePicture.

Comment: Apparently, the aspect ratios of selected PictureSize and PreviewSize don't match. It is a good idea to choose matching sizes (e.g. preview: 1280x720, picture: 3640x2048). Make sure that both PictureSize and PreviewSize are supported for the active camera. Many glitches have been observed on different devices when the aspect ratios were not matching.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a late answer, but anyways, I wanted to share my solution to this problem.

All you need to do in order to solve this problem is the following:

1. Get all supported picture sizes using the Camera.Params.getSupportedPictureSizes() method.
2. Find the most acceptable sizes and store them in a temporary container(ArrayList will work just fine)
3. Find the size you want to use, and actually provide the camera with the size you want to use, trought the Camera.Params.setPictureSize(width, height)
4. This is not really a fourth step, it's rather an addition to the 3rd one.
   In most cases your camera will have the incorrect orientation set by default, so will the image if not adjusted beforehand.
   So, I would strongly suggest you to use the Camera.Params.setRotation(angle)
   for the picture orientation change, and the Camera.Params.setDisplayOrientation(angle) for the preview orientation change.

And here is the code that's gonna do the thing with the picture size:

```
public static final float CAMERA_SIZE_RATIO_CALIBRATION = 0.1f;

private Camera.Size findTheBestPictureSize() {
    List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = mCamera.getParams().getSupportedPictureSizes();
    ArrayList<Camera.Size> acceptableSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>();

    Camera.Size foundSize = null;
    Camera.Size tmpSize = null;
    float desiredRatio = (mDisplaySize[0] * 1f / mDisplaySize[1]);
    float calculatedRatio;
    float deltaRatio = 0f;

    //Looking for the most acceptable sizes
    int itemCount = supportedSizes.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        tmpSize = supportedSizes.get(i);

        calculatedRatio = (shouldSizeDimensionsBeFlipped ? (tmpSize.height * 1f / tmpSize.width) 
                : (tmpSize.width * 1f / tmpSize.height));

        deltaRatio = Math.abs(calculatedRatio - desiredRatio);

        if(deltaRatio <= CAMERA_SIZE_RATIO_CALIBRATION) {
            acceptableSizes.add(tmpSize);
        }
    }

    //Looking for the greatest acceptable size
    itemCount = acceptableSizes.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        tmpSize = acceptableSizes.get(i);

        if(foundSize == null) {
            foundSize = tmpSize;
            continue;
        }

        if(tmpSize.width > foundSize.width && tmpSize.height > foundSize.height) {
            foundSize = tmpSize;
        }
    }

    return foundSize;
}
```

Where the shouldSizeDimensionsBeFlipped is a boolean value which determines whether we need to consider the fetched from the camera sizes as flipped(where width is taken as height, and height as width) or not(we will only need to do so, if the default Camera orientation is everything but 0 and 270)

I hope this is going to help someone who's having the same problem :)